# Apple rejected my app because of using MTStatusBarOverlay?

Tags: ios6, app-store, appstore-approval, iphone-privateapi

Apple just rejected my app due to using "private api" related to status bar overlays. However, I only on MTStatusBarOverlay library for the status bar overlay.

[image]

Is MTStatusBarOverlay forbidden by Apple?  [MTStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay) should be included in some apps on app store, as stated in their Github page.

Below is the only place I called MTStatusBarOverlay library:

```
+(void) displayMSGOnStatusBar:(NSString *)msg
{
    MTStatusBarOverlay *overlay = [MTStatusBarOverlay sharedInstance];
    overlay.animation = MTStatusBarOverlayAnimationFallDown;  
    overlay.detailViewMode = MTDetailViewModeHistory;       
    [overlay postImmediateMessage:msg duration:1.5 animated:YES];
}
```

Anyone know where the issue is? Your suggestion/help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Could you comment on why your app got rejected and how you fixed it? There are no mentions of apps being rejected because of MTStatusBarOverlay on the github page itself. Cheers.

Comment: @epologee Due to tire deadline, we had to removed the MTStatusBarOverlay from the app. However, according to this post, this might just be occasional rejection. You can still have a try.  https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay/issues/43

Comment: Thanks for following up. I think I'll try if the review boards accepts it in a later release, to prevent compromising the initial launch.

Comment: I was thinking of adding a custom status bar as well but after this it got me thinking.. Maybe as a temporary option I could hide the status bar completely and add a UIView instead resembling the actual status bar (black background, time, signal strength..) + my custom text.. Will this be approved? Or would they deny this on the facts that it will be a close match to the actual status bar and users would get confused? I cant afford to get rejected due to project deadline.. Thank you..

Comment: @snksnk As you realised, what you are doing is trying to mimic iPhone's status bar. This idea is quite dangerous once found out by Apple. Why don't you just put a small label containing your text on top of (half of the) status bar? I think it sounds better.

Comment: @Jiequan I want to include though the signal strength and time + custom text in a full screen app.. I think Apple only allows status bar customization as background color is  concerned..

Comment: The apple review process is really chaotic.  I have several apps which use MTStatusBar and several which get rejected by Apple for using it

Answer (score 1):

Just couple of thoughts:

a) Approval process doesn't guarantee to catch 100% of offending behavior. So, they may rejected your app, but they may have approved app which did very similar things.

b) MTStatusBarOverlay was actively developed about a year ago. It could be that Apple approval guidelines changed for this period of time.

c) Based on the description of rejection, they reject exactly the behavior of MTStatusBarOverlay (they don't like overlays on top of UIStatusBar).